# OOB SharePoint Work Flow question: Difference between Workflow Task and Tasks (New)

Tags: workflow, workflow-tasks-list

I'm studying up on adding an OOB Workflow for a list.  When I am at the Add a Workflow form, there is a drop down element called "Select a Task List:" with two choices:  "Workflow Tasks" and "Tasks (New)".  What is the difference between the two?  The description really isn't self-explanatory.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are just task lists. Each workflow can log its user tasks to a different task list. Selecting "Tasks (new)" will create a new task list named "yourWorkflowName Tasks". The default task list for workflows is "Workflow Tasks".

Comment: @mike-smith-mct-mvp, thanks.  I see there is a list called "Workflow Tasks".  I'll try the Task (new) just to test it out.

Again, many thanks.